# Apache load balancing with RewriteCond not working?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, load-balancing, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I have installed the apache httpd service and tried to set up load balancing.
I want to rewrite requests on a specific condition - when the Host header is "images.server.com", I want to rewrite the request, adding "/images/" to the URI and then proxy it to my upstream server.
The mod_proxy module comes perfectly for the task: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html
Well, not so great - my setup is the following:

```
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
      BalancerMember http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ="images.server.com"
    RewriteRule "/(.*)" "/images/%1" [P]
    ProxyPass /images balancer://mycluster/images
```

and it is not working :(
Please help me figure out where is the flaw in this configuration.

P.S. I have loaded the modules:

```
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

Comment: What do you observe? Why not use a virtual host and omit rewrite altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use both the 'P' flag and ProxyPass.  If you're going to use the 'P' flag, use balancer://... in the substitution and drop ProxyPass entirely.

Comment: I removed the ProxyPass... same result

Comment: Did you change the substitution int he rewriterule? To what?  What did you observe?

Comment: Yes. RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://mycluster/images/%1 [P] The behaviour is the same: 404, as if it searches the location without the /images/ part

Comment: Progress: I removed the quotes from the string value in the write condition and now it gets redirected to images.server.com but on https